# WPF MVVM getting the textbox data to the ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have read many questions on this and so far I've not been able to find the answer on this apparently simple issue.

I have a view model, in which is a property. In my XAML I have a TextBox with a binding to that property.

But the property never seems to change.

Here's the textbox:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.Column="0"
         Margin="4"
         Text="{Binding CharNameFromTB}" />
```

And the relevant code behind for the ViewModel:

```
private String _charNameFromTB;
String CharNameFromTB
{
    get { return _charNameFromTB; }

    set
    {
        if (!string.Equals(this._charNameFromTB, value))
        {
            this._charNameFromTB = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CharNameFromTB");
        }
    }
}
```

I have put a break point on the if statement in the setter, but it never triggers. Have I missed something obvious out? I tried setting the binding mode to twoway but that didn't change anything.

It's driving me a little mad. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `Text="{Binding CharNameFromTB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Check your output window, errors with bindings don't crash the code instead they output the error to the output window, this should always be your first check if a binding doesn't seem to be working

Comment: if that doesn't help the next port of call is to user a dedug converter https://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html

Comment: Grab Snoop.  You can examine your bindings at runtime and see errors immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the property `public` in order to be able to bind to it:

```
private String _charNameFromTB;
public String CharNameFromTB
{
    get { return _charNameFromTB; }

    set
    {
        this._charNameFromTB = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CharNameFromTB");
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you have set the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` or any of its parent elements to an instance of your view model class where the `CharNameFromTB` property is defined.

Also note that by default, the source property is set when the `TextBox` loses focus.

If you want to update the source property on each keystroke you should set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the `Binding` to `PropertyChanged`:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.Column="0"
         Margin="4"
         Text="{Binding CharNameFromTB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```